# Beyond LICQ in KKT problem: can't I study irregular points as follows?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

Given the following minimization problem
$$min f(x,y)=-x-y$$ in the region described by $ x-4y+3 \geq 0$, $-x+y^2 \geq 0$, $x \geq 0$,

I notice that the origin is an irregular point.
In fact, gradients of constraints, evaluated in the origin, are
$$\nabla g_1(x,y) = (1,-4) $$ $$\nabla g_2(x,y) = (-1,2y) = (-1,0)$$ $$\nabla g_3(x,y) = (1,0)$$.

If I consider the Jacobian matrix given by $ ( \nabla g_2 \nabla g_3 ) $ (g2 and g3 are the active constraints in the origin), I notice that I don't have full rank, so the gradients are linearly dependent (LICQ violated! Linear independence constraint qualification: the gradients of the active inequality constraints and the gradients of the equality constraints are linearly independent).
The exercise solution just states that in this case, we go on because we can't apply KKT conditions, so we aren't able to exclude that (0,0) is a point of minimum.

However, I tried to follow the proceeding that many use to explain the geometrical meaning of KKT conditions and I think I can say something more.

[image]

$g_1$ and $g_2$ are the constraints gradients (let's ignore their amplitude).
If (0,0) is a min point, then there's no descent direction that is also feasible. In (0,0) the only feasible directions (I need to stay in the region) are $d_1$ and $d_2$. If I want to "forbid" descent feasible direction, I need to force the gradient to belong to x axis. In that way (and this is the only case!) both of feasible directions aren't descent directions.
In the exercise situation, $\nabla f$ is $(-1,-1)$ so we just conclude that 0 is *not* a point of minimum, because one of the feasible directions defines with $\nabla f$ an obtuse angle (i.e. descent direction).

I tried to generalize the reasoning further, I came to the conclusion (probably false!) that when I deal with irregular points, I should consider the cone generated by the gradients. If the cone is not well defined (i.e. the gradients are aligned but opposite) and I have *two* cones/half-planes generated by them, then I should consider the intersection between half-planes that contain at least a feasible direction. You won't believe me, but I found a variety of cases in which the rule seems to work.
Is it a correct idea?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please, explain what is LICQ or give a reference.

Comment: @JeanMarie: Linear independence of active constraint qualification.

Comment: @JeanMarie fixed, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be a little careful here.

With the problem $\min \{ f(x) | g_k(x) \le 0 \}$, if $x$ is a local optimum
then there are non negative multipliers, not all zero, such that
$\mu_0 \nabla f(x) + \sum_k \mu_k \nabla g_k(x) = 0$
 (Fritz John).

The LICQ are sufficient conditions that guarantee that $\mu_0 \neq 0$, in this
case they do not hold at $(0,0)$ so the conclusion doesn't apply, and,
from an exercise perspective, you are done.

The optimality conditions are first order, so, loosely, they do not distinguish
problems that have the same gradients at a point.

Hence the problems $P_1: \ \min \{ -x-y | -x \le 0, x - y^2 \le 0 \} $
and $P_2: \ \min \{ -x-y | -x +2y|y|\le 0, x - y^2 \le 0 \} $ 'look' the same from a
first order optimality condition perspective, however, $(0,0)$ is not a
local minimum for $P_1$, but is a local minimum for $P_2$.

In particular, from gradient information alone, you **cannot** exclude $(0,0)$
as a potential local minimum.

However, we can do a little better if we include more information. Let
$C = \{ x | g_k (x) \le 0 \}$ (the feasible set) and suppose $x \in C$,
then we can define the cone of feasible directions at $x$ as
$D_C(x) = \{ h | \exists \delta>0,  x+th \in C \  \forall t \in [0,\delta] \}$.

For $P_1$, we have $D_C((0,0)) = \{ (0,t) \}_{t \in \mathbb{R} }$ and
for $P_2$, we have $D_C((0,0)) = \{ (0,t) \}_{t \le 0 }$.

Then we see if there is a direction of descent for $f$ contained in $D_C((0,0))$.

Since $\langle \nabla f((0,0)), (0,1) \rangle < 0$, we see that $(0,0)$
cannot be a local minimum for $P_1$, however since
$\langle \nabla f((0,0)), h \rangle \ge 0$ for all $h \in D_C((0,0))$,
we cannot exclude $(0,0)$ as a local minimum for $P_2$.

There are many generalisations and variants of the constraint tangent cone.

Also note that you need to look at the dual cone of the convex cone formed
by the active gradients, not the cone itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. First of all, I can't understand why wolfram doesn't agree with your assertion on P2 minimum ( look at this http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=local+min+f(x,y)%3D-x-y,+%E2%88%92x%2B2y%7Cy%7C%E2%89%A40,x%E2%88%92y2%E2%89%A40 ). Secondly, I don't understand why I am wrong. Looking at geometric "proof" of KKT conditions, I can't understand in which point of my reasoning I made unjustified assumptions. :(

Comment: @Surferonthefall: Because my example has a bug, will fix.

Comment: @Surferonthefall: Actually, it is a local minimum for $P_2$ but not a global one (it is unbounded below as stated).

Comment: Do you see why you need to deal with the dual cone generated by the gradients?

Comment: mmmh in the exercise case what is the dual cone of the active gradients? I think it is the x axis, so I need the target function gradient to be along it.. Am i wrong?

Comment: The dual cone is the $y$ axis in this case and consists of $\{h | \langle \nabla g_k((0,0)) , h \rangle \ge 0 , \forall k \text{ active}\}$. A feasible direction must lie in the negative of the dual cone (otherwise some constraint will be violated locally).

Comment: you're right, sorry. ok, the feasible directions are the red arrows that I drew on the plot. now the question is: If I want to descend I need to pick a direction such that $\langle \nabla f((0,0)), d \rangle < 0$. If $\nabla f$ is along x axis, none of the red arrows satisfy that. In any other case, one of them satisfy that. I conclude that if (0,0) is min point, $\nabla f$ is along x axis. Why am I wrong? :(

Comment: The problem here is that there is a direction $(0,1)$ that is a descent direction, but you need to be sure that moving in that direction does not violate the constraints. For $P_1$ this is the case, for $P_2$ it is not. Also, $\nabla f((0,0)) = (-1,-1)^T$, I'm not sure what you mean by the gradient being along the $x$ axis.

Comment: yeees! I already said that 0 is *not* a minimum point, I can exclude it just because as you said (0,1) is a descent direction! But if it was a min point then the function gradient would be something like $\mu (1,0)$ (along x axis).. Do you agree?

Comment: Well, you cannot exclude $(0,0)$ just on gradient information. $(0,1)$ is a descent direction, but, on gradient info. alone you cannot tell that it is a feasible direction (that is why I had the $P_2$ which has the same gradient info., but $(0,1)$ is not a feasible descent direction). I still have no idea what you mean when you talk about the function gradient being anything other than $(-1,1)^T$.

Comment: at first, let's stick with the exercise case, please. In the question I did not say that gradient info alone is enough to conclude anything. I said: textbooks just say "there's no KKT cone in which the $\nabla f$ has to stay, because of LICQ violation". I say: in this case we could call "KKT cone" the degenerate cone, generated by the two active gradients, we have the x axis. Then we want to check: is the function gradient within our cone? No, it isn't. Then, it can't be a min point (because I can find a desc. feas. d). I found this naive rule to apply correctly to different situations.

Comment: About your P2: http://imgur.com/a/w7NwM . Yellow arrow: function gradient. Red arrows: feasible directions (in fact if I infinitesimally move toward the positive y I still stay in the feasible region, even if the frontier). The upward red arrow is a descent direction. So it is not a min point. Even in this example, the function gradient not being in the degenerate cone generated by active gradients, the x axis, guarantees for a descent feasible direction!

Comment: This is getting a little too difficult to properly respond to in comments. First, you **are** trying conclude something based on gradient information. You wrote 'is the function gradient within our cone [generated by the two active gradients]?' Second, you should be looking for a descent direction in the **dual** cone (or its negative, depending on definition) generated by the active constraint gradients. Third, the point of $P_2$ is that it has exactly the same gradient info. at $(0,0)$, but has a local minimum at $(0,0)$. It is easy to show that $y \le 0$ for any feasible $(x,y)$.

Comment: You need to enlarge the cone of feasible direction beyond that provided by gradient info. alone. That was the point of my adding the $D_C(x)$ set above.