# How to solve a Karush-Kuhn-Tucker example

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, solution-verification, nonlinear-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

This is a problem example taken from  professor [Robert Israel](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/%7Eisrael/m340/kkt2.pdf):

$$\max f(x,y)=xy \quad \text{subject to }\quad   x+y^2\leq2, \quad x,y\geq0 \quad \quad (1)$$

The solution begins by writing the KKT conditions for this problem, and then one reach the conclusion that the global optimum is $(x^*,y^*)=(4/3,\sqrt{2/3})$.

However the linear independence constraint qualification (LICQ) fails everywhere, so in principle the KKT approach cannot be used directly. I have seen multiple examples solved like this, and I don't understand why this is legitimate.

It seems to me that the correct approach would be to reason as follows:

Suppose $(x^*,y^*)$ is a constrained local maximum for the problem. Then we see that neither of the nonnegativity constraints can bind at $(x^*,y^*)$, because otherwise every neighborhood of $(x^*,y^*)$ would contain a feasible point $(x,y)$ with $f(x,y)>0=f(x^*,y^*)$. Therefore $(x^*,y^*)$ is a constrained local maximum for the problem

$$\max f(x,y)=xy \quad \text{subject to }\quad   x+y^2\leq2 \quad \quad (2)$$

which satisfies the LICQ condition everywhere. Using the KKT conditions gives $(x^*,y^*)=(4/3,\sqrt{2/3})$.

For sufficiency, we note that $f$ is continuous and that the feasible set in $(1)$ is compact, so $f$ attains a global maximum at some feasible $(x^*,y^*)$. Combined with the previous necessity argument, we conclude that  $(x^*,y^*)=(4/3,\sqrt{2/3})$ is the unique local and global maximum for the problem.

Am I missing something? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: How do you get LICQ fails everywhere?

Comment: @mattos The gradients of the $3$ constraints are $\begin{bmatrix}1\\2y\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: @Alphie Be sure you are testing the gradients of the active constraints at a point only, i.e. only those that give equality at the point.

Comment: I think [this might answer your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1969773/beyond-licq-in-kkt-problem-cant-i-study-irregular-points-as-follows?rq=1).

Comment: @A.Γ. Yes thats my point; we need to argue that the constraints $x,y\geq0$ are not binding at the local optimum $(x^*,y^*)$, and therefore discard them before writing the KKT conditions.

Comment: @Alphie No, the behaviour of constraints at the (local) max is not necessary to know. Instead, you are to test all points in the set. It is normally done by splitting into cases where different constraints are active/non-active. Algebraically, it is often controlled by the complementary slackness condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CQ is to be tested for *active* constraints (that become equalities) at a point only. Here you have three constraints:

1. $x+y^2\le 2$,
2. $x\ge 0$,
3. $y\ge 0$.

Case 1: only one constraint of those three is active: gradients are non-zero, i.e. LICQ ok.

Case 2: $x=y=0$, $x+y^2<2$: gradients $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ are linearly independent, i.e. LICQ ok.

Case 3: $x=x+y^2-2=0$, $y>0$, and Case 4: $y=x+y^2-2=0$, $x>0$ - left as an exercise.

Case 5: all three are active: not possible.

Comment: Thank you I understand now. There is also the case of all constraints being inactive, but the LICQ condition holds trivially in this case. Do you think my reasoning about the contraints $x,y\geq0$ being inactive at $(x^*,y^*)$ is also correct ?

Comment: @Alphie All constraints inactive is not really the case in CQ, it is the case in KKT. Your reasoning about the effect of $x=0$ or $y=0$ on the maximum of $xy$ is correct. It works though quite rare, here it is thanks to $f(x,y)\ge 0$ in the set.

Comment: Ok I see. Can I also argue that the constraint $x+y^2\le 2$ must be active at a local maximum? Otherwise I could increase $x$ or $y$ slightly and increase my objective.

Comment: What do you mean by : all contraints inactive is not really the case in CQ?

Comment: @Alphie CQ conditions are an attempt to avoid pathological behavior of constraints where the set of feasible directions is empty. This pathology always happens at the boundary, i.e. some constraint is active. No active constraint means interior point, and the cone of feasible direction is the whole space. KKT gives $\nabla f=0$ as in unconstraint optimization (all Lagrange multiplier are zeros).

Comment: @Alphie Yes, you may argue that the constraint $x+y^2\le 2$ must be active, otherwise there is a feasible direction pointing at larger objective values. However, it is not a KKT argumentation. It is ad hoc argumentation coming from the particular outlook of the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I will confess that I don't know this "KKT" method! I have to solve it with basic "Calculus methods".

We want to maximize f(x,y)= xy subject to the condition that $x+ y^2\le 2$.  The graph of $x= 2- y^2$ is a parabola with vertex (2, 0) that crosses the y-axis at $(0, \sqrt{2})$ and $(0, -\sqrt{2})$.  $\nabla f= y\vec{i}+ x\vec{j}= 0$ at (0, 0).  The maximum of f occurs either at (0, 0) (and f(0,0)= 0) or on that parabola.  On the parabola $x= 2- y^2$, $f(x,y)= f(2- y^2, y)= (2- y^2)y= 2y- y^3$.  Setting $F(y)= 2y- y^3$, $F'= 2- 3y^2= 0$.  $y^2= 2/3$, y= 2/3 or y= -2/3.  If y= 2/3, x= 2- 4/9= 14/9, f(x,y)= f(14/9,2/3)= 28/27.   If y= -2/3, x= 2- 14/9= 4/9, f(x, y)= f(4/9, -2/3)= -8/27.

Of those three values, -8/27, 0, and 28/27, the largest is 28/27 which occurs at (14/8, 2/3
).

Comment: $F'(y)= 2- 2y^2 $... ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I have edited my post so that I can pretend I didn't make that silly mistake!

Comment: Its still incorrect: $y^2= 2/3$ implies $y=\pm \sqrt{2/3}$